# how do you get the rails image path when you don't want to use an image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I'm using slimbox2 with rails. To make it work you include some markup as follows:

```
<a href="resources/images/weight1.jpg" rel="lightbox-a" title="Beautiful, isn't it?">a</a> 

<a href="resources/images/example.jpg" rel="lightbox-a" title="Beautiful, isn't it?">a</a>
```

So I'm wondering, how do you grab the location of the image to place in the href?  Relative addressing?  Is their a helper that is useful in this situation?

Comment: It's better to follow Rails conventions by placing your images in the public/images directory rather than some other location. Could you please explain why you're breaking convention?

Answer (score 12):

You want the path of an image? You might try the aptly named [#image_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path) helper method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this. The helper is marginally useful. Honestly, unless there's some dynamic component, there's nothing wrong with just using HTML

```
link_to("a","/resources/images/weight1.jpg", :rel=>"lightbox-a", :title=>"Beautiful, isn't it?")
```

If the image is dynamic, you could always assign a variable with the path to the image (determined how you like)

```
<a href="<%= @image_path %>" rel="lightbox-a" title="Foo" />a</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming the images were in your public/images folder, you could achieve that with something like

```
<%= link_to 'a', image_path('weight1.jpg'), :rel => 'lightbox-a', :title => 'some title' %>
```